Proof of Greatest Lower Bound Thoerem on subsets for all sets $A, B, C, C \subseteq A \cap B$ iff $(C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B)$
The current problem I am working on is from the book An Introduction to Mathematical Proofs by Nicholas A. Loehr. What follows is the problem statement and my work, which I think is correct, but feedback from someone else that I'm thinking "properly" would be nice. If it's right, hopefully it will be helpful for someone else checking their work like me.
Exercise 3.1.1. Prove Greatest Lower Bound on subsets: for all sets $A$, $B$, $C$, $C \subseteq A \cap B$ iff $(C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B)$.
Here is a related question, which is only concerned with the backwards implication.

Here's my work:
$\left( \Longrightarrow \right)$: Assume $C \subseteq A \cap B$ and fix any $x_{0}\in C$. Since $x_{0}\in C$ and $C \subseteq A \cap B$, we deduce $x_0 \in A \cap B$. By the definition of set intersection, $x_0 \in A \cap B$ means that $x_0 \in A$ and $x_0 \in B$. Since $x_0 \in A$ and $x_0 \in B$ for any $x_0 \in C$, it follows that $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$.
$\left( \Longleftarrow \right)$: Suppose $C \subseteq A$ and $C \subseteq B$, and let $x_{0}$ be any object in $C$. Since $x_{0} \in C$, while $C\subseteq A$ and $C\subseteq B$, we infer that $x_{0}\in A$ and $x_{0}\in B$. By definition of set intersection, $x_{0}\in A\cap B$, but note $x_{0}\in C$, so $C\subseteq A\cap B$.
